# Maven build fails after adding to application.properties

Tags: spring, maven

I'd like to create a java file with a database.

Running a Maven build works but as soon as I add anything to **application.properties** it fails.

heres what I'm adding to the **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:defaultdb.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto update
```

EDIT:

Here's the error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.javabackendfinal.JavaBackendFinalApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.088 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.javabackendfinal.JavaBackendFinalApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.javabackendfinal.JavaBackendFinalApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.sqlite.JDBC
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.sqlite.JDBC
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.sqlite.JDBC
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

Comment: kindly share the logs. check the syntax for this ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto update``` ```=``` is missing.

Comment: This is clearly not the issue with maven build, as your maven build is no way related to spring-boot's  `application.properties`. Please try `mvn validate` to see if your `pom.xml` is structured properly. Also if you are expecting answers please articulate your problem properly and provide supporting logs.

Comment: Okay. Added the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this dependency in your pom.xml file. It should get rid of this error. `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.sqlite.JDBC` This shows that it's unable to find the required class file on the classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.27.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```